# Need help to storing an map of type interface in my mongodb database using golang

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, go, struct, mgo

I m in the process of creating application where my back end is in go lang and database is mongoDB. My problem is that  i have a map in my struct declared like

```
Data struct {
        data   map[interface{}]interface{}
}
```

after adding values in to this like

```
var data Data
    data["us"]="country"
    data[2]="number"
    data["mother"]="son"
```

I m inserting it like

```
c.Insert(&data)
```

When i insert this i m losing my key  and can only see the values...

```
{
    "_id" : Object Id("57e8d9048c1c6f751ccfaf50"),
    "data" : {
        "<interface {} Value>" : "country",
        "<interface {} Value>" : "number",
        "<interface {} Value>" : "son"
    },

}
```

May i know any way possible to use interface and get both  key and values in my mongoDB. Thanks....

Comment: Your keys in the map are going to be `string` right? Use `map[string]interface{}`. Or if you're certain of the data type (i.e. your value is always string, just use `map[string]string`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nothing but `string` as key in MongoDB documents. Even if you would define your `Data` structure as `map[int]interface{}` Mongo (don't know if `mgo` will convert types) wouldn't allow you to insert this object into the database. Actually, you can use nothing but `string` as JSON key at all as this wouldn't be JSON (try in your browser console the next code `JSON.parse('{2:"number"}')`).

So define your `Data` as `bson.M` (shortcut for `map[string]interface{}`) and use `strconv` package to convert your numbers into strings.

But I guess you must look at arrays/slices, as only one reason why someone may need to have numbers as keys in JSON is iterations through these fields in future. And for iterations we use arrays.

*Update: just checked how `mgo` deals with `map[int]interface{}`. It inserts into DB entry like `{"<int Value>" : "hello"}`. Where `<int Value>` is not number but actually [string `<int Value>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frklK.png)*